# bootstrap CSS @media not working in laravel

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, media-queries

I am a newbie in Laravel. In my project, I try to load `bootstrap` correctly to blade template. Everythings is fine except CSS @media, view is only rendered with normal CSS class in bootstrap but not CSS class in media. This is my code:
This is `index.blade.php` view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>
            Laravel Sample Site
        </title>            
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:yellow;height:100px;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red;height:100px;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`media-queries` are included in bootstrap css.

And this is my public structure:

```
public/
    /bootstrap/
        /css
        /js
        /font
    /assets
        /css
        /js
        /font
        /images
```

As expect, View must contain 2 column with same width but when I run View only contain 2 row (exactly means bootstrap css layout not work)

Comment: Can you post the media query? I don't fully understand your question

Comment: I use twitter bootstrap so @media was included in bootstrap css file

Answer (score 1):

Laravel produces HTML and where your .css file is included and it does not have further relation to the browser that is handling media queries.

In your HTML it looks like the bootstrap .js is missing.

You can experiment with static .html code in your browser to see where is the error in using the bootstrap in your case. Right now this case does not have information of your HTML which does not respond to the @media queries.

Comment: I tried to use HTML, everything work well. So I think problem come from Laravel?

Comment: If media query does not behave the way you want it to then problem is in pure frontend (html, css, js). Laravel is just producing the HTML for you. There must be difference in your test html and HTML produced by Laravel. If you will post the HTML/CSS snippet what is not working hten it can be possible to point out what is wrong in there.

Comment: HTML and blade.php file are completely same, and in browser, I view-source: they are same too, in laravel, boostrap css file loaded completely.